# PL SQL-case based on count

Tags: plsql

I have the table:

```
ID  own1    own2    status
t1  A   B   1
t1  B   C   0
t1  C   A   0
t1  A   D   0
t1  D   F   0
t2  D   E   1
t2  E   A   0
t3  A   B   1
t3  B   C   0
t4  A   B   1
t5  E   D   1
```

i want to find the value of column own2 group by ID, based on the value of the counting of column status. That is, if the count(status)<=1 then own2 else the_last_value of own2.

For example, for ID t1 the desired result will be 'F', for t2 'A', for t3 'C', for t4  'B'

Comment: The result of count(status) doesn't seem to factor into your logic at all; and I don't see why t2 is 'A' since the maximum (last?) value is 'E'.

Answer (score 0):

The question is hard to follow, but making some assumptions about what I *think* you mean and what the data is doing - specifically that status 0 has priority over 1 for a given id/own1, and by 'last' you mean with the highest own1 value, and that referring to the count of statuses is at best misleading - I came up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
    FIRST_VALUE(OWN2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STATUS, OWN1 DESC) AS OWN2
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY ID;
```

Which gives:

```
ID OWN2
-- ----
t1 F
t2 A
t3 C
t4 B
t5 D
```

(This also assumes the PLSQL tag implies you're using Oracle, which might not be true as the question doesn't see to relate to PL/SQL either.)